# How to get cpu usage of current tab from chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am using the chrome extension api chrome.processes and chrome.tabs and have been trying to get the cpu usage of current tab only.

I looked at the chromium example code for reference but the purpose of its code is to display all information of all the processes on chrome but i only need the current tab"s information.

this is my code

```
var tid;
var cpu;

chrome.tabs.get(tabid, function(tabid) {
    tid = tabid.id;
});
chrome.processes.onUpdatedWithMemory.addListener(
    function(processes) {
        for (pid in processes) {
            if (processes[pid].id = tid) {

                cpu = processes[pid].id.cpu;
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

I didn't receive any error message but when I debug it, the value of tid is always undefined and the processes array is looping fine.

Comment: Use chrome.processes.getProcessIdForTab to get the process id, then find it in the results.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried using it but it requires the tab id in order to return the process id. But I can't get the tab id as well.

Comment: See 1) [How can I get the current tab URL for chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/17826527) and use the tab's id **inside** the callback or switch to Promise via Mozilla's WebExtension polyfill 2) [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](//stackoverflow.com/q/23667086) 3) [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)